# Multiple draw calls per ModelInstance LibGDX?

Tags: opengl, optimization, libgdx

I have about thirty ModelInstances on the screen. Each is an animated chicken. When I try to profile the draw calls, I get about 5 draw calls per each model instance. Is there a way to combine these at least for each instance? I've tried combining the meshes but I'm very unaware of what to do with bone transformations, and the transforms for each mesh part. Where can I begin to lower the draw calls?
Each is drawn using:

```
batch.begin(cam);
batch.render(instances, environment);
batch.end();
```

Other facts: each model has 5 materials, and three bones.

Comment: 5 materials -> 5 draw calls. Find a way to combine the materials into a single material.

Comment: Any idea how to do that? If I changed the materials to a UV mapped texture would that reduce the number of draw calls? Even further, would it be worth it performance wise to do that?